# Position divs center verticaly and horizontally

Tags: html, css

There are a few divs. I want to set width of `black` as needed and put it on the middle (horizontally) of `red`. Then put some elements in `black` in one line and position them on the middle (vertically) of `black`.

The final result should looks like:

[image]

There is a problem with center vertically.
My code is:

```
<html>
    <body>  
        <div id="mainContainer">
          <div id="singleOptions">
            <div id="myObject"></div>
            <div id="mySecondObject"></div>
          </div>
        </div>      
    </body>
    <style>
        #mainContainer {
          background: red;
          width: 100px;
          height: 100px;
          margin-top: 50px;
          text-align: center;
        }
        #singleOptions {
          height: 100%;
          background: black;
          display: inline-block;
        }
        #myObject {
          width: 10px;
          display: inline-block;
          height: 10px;
          background: green;
        }   
        #mySecondObject {
          width: 10px;
          display: inline-block;
          height: 10px;
          background: yellow;
        }
    </style>
</html>
```

How is it possible to get this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it like this

```css
#mainContainer {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#singleOptions {
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: min-content;
  align-items: center;
}

#myObject {
  width: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background: green;
}

#mySecondObject {
  width: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="singleOptions">
      <div id="myObject"></div>
      <div id="mySecondObject"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox):

```css
#mainContainer {
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
#singleOptions {
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
#myObject {
    width: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 10px;
    background: green;
}   
#mySecondObject {
    width: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 10px;
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="singleOptions">
    <div id="myObject"></div>
    <div id="mySecondObject"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is solved easily with [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Change your CSS for `#singleOptions` as follows.

```css
#singleOptions {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```